# Set Hudson Build Description via Web API

Tags: python, hudson, hudson-api

I have a Python script that operates on Hudson builds and would love to be able to set the description of a build programmatically.

I can click "Add Description" on a build's page and fill in the form, how can I POST some data to the same URL that form does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out, need to POST the following as form data (content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) to

http://myserver/hudson/job/thebuild/10/submitDescription

```
{"description": "Some Description for the build"}
```

In code:

```
def set_description(build_url, desc):
    req_data = urllib.urlencode({'description': desc})
    req = urllib2.Request(build_url + '/submitDescription', req_data)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: I'm using Jenkins and I'm getting a 403 when I try this. Anyone know if this still works in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

(would comment, but not enough rep)

Thanks to jtb for the bulk of the approach. If security is enabled on the server, I found that I could authenticate using this code (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077475/can-i-do-preemptive-authentication-with-httplib2))

```
def set_description(build_url, desc, user, token):
    import base64, urllib, urllib2
    req_data = urllib.urlencode( {'description': desc } )
    req = urllib2.Request(build_url + '/submitDescription', req_data)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    auth = 'Basic {}'.format(base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format( user, token )))
    req.add_header( 'Authorization', auth )
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

The values for user and token can be found under API Token in: `http://<myserver>/me/configure`

Answer (score 2):

Using an 'Execute system Groovy script' Build task:

```
import hudson.model.Cause
import hudson.model.Job
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

final JOB_NAME = 'my-job-name'

final jenkins = Jenkins.instance
final job = jenkins.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME, Job.class)
final currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
final buildNumber = currentBuild.getNumber()

job.builds
    .findAll { build ->
        build.number == buildNumber
    }
    .each { build ->
        build.setDescription("Some Description for the build")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the curl command that worked fine from shell. Replace the text in between and including {}.

curl -X POST -u {user:password} -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode description={descriptionstring} {hudsonurl}/job/{jobname}/{buildnumber}/submitDescription