# How to pass through Jenkins credentials?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to follow the advice given in [Set Hudson Build Description via Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870187/set-hudson-build-description-via-web-api) but I'm getting a 403 presumably because the request has to be authenticated. Since the script is being run from an authenticated Jenkins session, how do I pass those credentials through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'Execute system Groovy script' Build task which executes in the same VM so you don't have to re-authenticate or manually pass through tokens or credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to pass user and api token in your request. [Here's an example](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) (not in Python, but I guess you can manage the translation).